# Displaying each category on a separate page - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

For a blog site, I have all the posts & lists of categories displaying on a page though now I need to display the posts for each category on it's own separate page.

Let's say I had a category that was 'Javascript' and I wanted only the posts with the category of javascript displayed on a page.

What's the correct code to do this? here's an example of what I have at the moment.

`categoriesController.php`

```
public function show($id)
{
$post->withCategories($Categories)->$id->($id as **javascript)**
}
```

`javascript.blade.php` ( corresponding view )

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($categories as $category->$id>**javascript**)
<tr>
<th>{{ $category->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div> <!-- end of .col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up the relations in the laravel models properly you could use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '=', 'javascript');
})->get();
```

However I would personally flip the order and load the `Category` first so you query it by name:

```
$category = Category::with('posts')->where('name', '=', 'javascript')->get();
```

And then in the view:

```
{{ $category->name }}<br>
@foreach(category->posts as $post)
    {{ $post->title }}<br>
@endforeach
```